# Passing value from Eval("Blah^^") to function in a js file via Onclick event of a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm a beginner
Here is my code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_ALlSongThumbs" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <a href='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SongName","index.aspx?SongName={0}") %>'><%# Eval("TrackName")%></a>
          <a href="#" runat="server" onclick="PlaySongNow()">
             <span><img src="database/singlecovers/<%# Eval("SongArt") %>" alt="cover"/></span>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </li>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Please help me to pass the value of <&#Eval(SongName)%> to the function PlaySongNow(_something-I-don't-know-how-to-code-here_The-value-of-Eval(TrackName) in the js file when the 2nd href is clicked on.
I was able to pass the specific file name like onclick="PlaySongNow('TwerkItLikeMiley-BB.mp3')"  .I've been looking for this on itnet for hours but I can't apply any solutions to my problem myself, It's kinda hard for me. Thank you.

Comment: onclick="PlaySongNow('<%#Eval("SongName") %>')"

Answer (score 0):

My html page:

```
        <div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rpt_ALlSongThumbs" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <li>
            <figure>
              <a href='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SongName","index.aspx?SongName={0}") %>'><%# Eval("TrackName")%></a>
              <a href="#"   onclick="PlaySongNow('<%# Eval("ProductID").ToString() %>')">
                 <span><img src="/images/<%# Eval("SongArt") %>" alt="cover"/></span>
              </a>
            </figure>
          </li>
      </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
```

And my code behind to make it work:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string SongName { get; set; }
    public string TrackName { get; set; }
    public string SongArt {get; set; }
}
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var products = new List<Product>();
        products.Add(new Product() { ProductID = 1, SongName = "Help", TrackName = "a track", SongArt = "bkg-blu.jpg" });
        products.Add(new Product() { ProductID = 2, SongName = "War", TrackName = "b track", SongArt="pjstripe.jpg"});
        products.Add(new Product() { ProductID = 3, SongName = "Sara", TrackName = "c track",   SongArt="pjstripe2.jpg" });

        rpt_ALlSongThumbs.DataSource = products;
        rpt_ALlSongThumbs.DataBind();
    }
}
```